# Using Blight on a tree construct?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, constructs, curse-of-strahd

In Curse of Strahd players will encounter

> Baba Lysaga's Creeping Hut

which is tagged as a gargantuan construct.

> The hut itself is a small shack placed on top/inside of a gigantic rotting tree stump/roots.

The druid in the campaign has Blight and **the question is can blight effect this specific construct, or no?**

Blight states:

> Necromantic energy washes over a creature of your choice that you can see within range, draining moisture and vitality from it. The target must make a Constitution saving throw. The target takes 8d8 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. This spell has no effect on undead or constructs.
>
> If you target a plant creature or a magical plant, it makes the saving
>   throw with disadvantage, and the spell deals maximum damage to it.

Clearly the monster is tagged as a construct, so blight shouldn't work, but it's also a gigantic tree, aka plant. Most constructs tend to be rock/metal/other and it makes sense to not be able to blight a suit of armor, for example. But since the material making up and moving the construct is plant matter is there some flexibility here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You quote the relevant passage in your question.

> This spell has no effect on undead or constructs.

Constructs are not of the creature type plant or vice versa. The Monster Manual has a list of creature types at the beginning of the book to help make a bit more sense out of this. Unlike previous editions a creature does not have multiple types so they are either one or the other.

This instance is "The Hut" was constructed out of plants but not creatures of type plant and the end type designated is also not of type plant.

Comment: you're not 100% correct about multiple types. Yes, the "main" types like construct, humanoid, fiend etc. are limited to 1 per creature. However, creatures may have multiple subtypes, such as the *Tanarukk* in *VGtM*, p. 186, which is a "Medium fiend (demon, orc)", which is relevant e.g. for a ranger who chose orcs as their favored enemy, but not demons/fiends.

Comment: @PixelMaster I would argue that subtypes are not types and were placed as an afterthought, possibly during the fleshing out of the Ranger class, as that and possibly Arrow of Slaying are the only niches of consequence that come to mind and possibly qualification for player class options (Bladesinger). In any event the umbrella type is the focus here, if they change the base rules to allow for multiple types or introduce a creature that has them I will edit this.

Answer (score 10):

You said it yourself: The hut is clearly tagged as a construct, so it's unaffected.  That's all the answer you need, by the rules-as-written.  The spell explicitly excludes this type of creature.

But to address the rest of the question more fully, the whole point of Blight is that it kills *living* plants. A "gigantic rotting tree stump" is already dead and rotting.  In other words, even if it weren't a construct, you couldn't blight it to death, because it's already there.

Comment: I guess in my mind i see blight making something like the roots brittle draining moisture out of them, but if the entire structure is moving purely because of magic, that would make that ineffective.

Comment: @Himarm Right.  A wood golem is made of wood, but it isn't a plant, it's just dead plant matter being driven around by a spirit.  The hut is basically the same thing.